# Destination attribute mapping not showing newly added attribute in xcmodelmappingmodel while Coredata migration

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, core-data-migration, modelmapper

I have a coredata mapping where `Version` model had 4 attributes

> appName, authCode, passPhrase, appVersion.

But on the next version of Coredata the `passPharse` entity was dropped. And no mapping for `passPhrase` was there.

Later I added another attribute in Version model

> oldPassPhrase

but on the Entity Mapping `VersionToVersion` it is not showing on Destination attribute dropdown. Other 3 attributes are there.

How can I get the `oldPassPhrase` attribute on Destination attribute dropdown of xcmodelmappingmodel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a new .xcmappingmodel solved my problem.